# Mapkit mapview is not showing on first try

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a tab on the RootViewController.m. The tab has 2 buttons. The first button upon click will go to CorpViewcontroller which has the mapView on it. When I click on the first button on the first try, the map is blank with google label on the bottom. I have to click back then click on the button again then the map show up. Is it possible to always show the map on the first button click?

My rootViewController.m to go to the second screen:

```
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.corpController animated:YES];
```

The second screen called corpViewController has the following code:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Set Remote Location";
    self.jsonData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    //Setup the double tap gesture for getting the remote location..
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    tgr.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    tgr.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [mapView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];

    mapView.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad  done");
    }


    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated    {

      NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");

      appDelegate = (NBSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

      double curLat = [appDelegate.curLat doubleValue];

      MKUserLocation *userLocation = mapView.userLocation;

      double miles = 10.0;
      double scalingFactor = ABS( (cos(2 * M_PI * curLat / 360.0) ));

      MKCoordinateSpan span; 

      span.latitudeDelta = miles/69.0;
      span.longitudeDelta = miles/(scalingFactor * 69.0); 

      MKCoordinateRegion region2;
      region2.span = span;
      region2.center = userLocation.coordinate;

      [mapView setRegion:region2 animated:YES];

       NSLog(@"viewWillAppear done..");

       }
```

Please Advise.

Thank you

Comment: On the first click, is the map all blue?  What happens if you comment out the setRegion line in viewWillAppear?

Comment: Yes map is all blue. If I commented out the setRegion, I do see the map now on the first try but it's not zooming in within 10 miles of the current location. Any suggestion? To make setRegion work on the first try.

Answer (score 3):

Are you initializing the MapView in the `viewDidLoad` method in your view controller?

If so, try moving it to the `viewDidAppear` method.  That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In `viewDidLoad` you are setting `showsUserLocation` to `YES` and in `viewWillAppear`, you are zooming into the `mapView.userLocation` coordinate.

The `userLocation` property isn't usually ready with a valid coordinate immediately after setting `showsUserLocation` to `YES`.

The first time you show the view controller, it's still invalid and you are zooming into the coordinate 0,0.

By the time you show the view controller a second time, the user location has been obtained and the coordinate is valid.

Instead of zooming into the user location in `viewWillAppear`, do it in the delegate method `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` which the map view calls when it gets a user location update.

In addition, you also probably want to move the `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;` to `viewWillAppear` and in `viewWillDisappear`, set it to `NO`.  This way, the map view will zoom in to the user location every time the view controller is shown instead of just the first time.

An unrelated point is that to zoom in to a specific distance, it's much easier to use the `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance` function instead of trying to convert miles to degrees yourself.

Here's an example of the changes suggested in `corpViewController`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //move this from viewDidLoad to here...
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
  //Changed the **internal** parameter name from mapView to mv
  //to avoid a compiler warning about it hiding instance var with same name.
  //It's better to use the passed parameter variable anyway.
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateUserLocation");

    double miles = 10.0;

    //Instead of manually calculating span from miles to degrees, 
    //use MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance function...
    //Just need to convert miles to meters.
    CLLocationDistance meters = miles * 1609.344;
    MKCoordinateRegion region2 = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance
                                   (userLocation.coordinate, meters, meters);

    [mv setRegion:region2 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I moved the mapView.showUserLocation = YES to viewWillAppear and set to NO in viewWillDisappear but the behavior is same on first try still blue screen. I put in didUpdateUserLocation but it never get call. I will try to the MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance to see if it helps - thx

Comment: Make sure you still set the delegate in viewDidLoad.  Show your didUpdateUserLocation method (add the code to the question).

Comment: Yes, I still have the delegate in ViewDidLoad and nothing in viewWillAppear. Move all the code into didUpdateUserLocation. On the first try, I do see the map of U.S. but the didUpdateUserLocation never get call thus, it's not zooming in.

Comment: Please show your didUpdateUserLocation method.  Note that it may still take a few seconds to get location.  Do you have location turned on in the simulator?  Also implement the "didFail" method and see if it gets called.  But it would help if you show the didUpdate method written.

Comment: - (void) mapView:didUpdateUserLocation {   
     NSLog(@" In didUpdateUserLocation..");
     mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;    
     appDelegate = (NBSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];   
     double curLat = [appDelegate.curLat doubleValue];
     MKUserLocation *userLocation = mapView.userLocation;

Comment: double miles = 10.0;
     double scalingFactor = ABS( (cos(2 * M_PI * curLat / 360.0) )); 
     MKCoordinateSpan span;    
     span.latitudeDelta = miles/69.0;
    span.longitudeDelta = miles/(scalingFactor * 69.0); 
    MKCoordinateRegion region2;
    region2.span = span;
    region2.center = userLocation.coordinate;   
    [mapView setRegion:region2 animated:YES];   
}

Comment: What is the didFail method signature? I tried mapView:didFail but it's not correct. Thx

Comment: It should be written `-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation` (not `-(void)mapView:didUpdateUserLocation`).  You also don't need to set showsUserLocation in that method.

Comment: it's still not being call.   -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateUserLocation"); 

    appDelegate = (NBSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    
    double curLat = [appDelegate.curLat doubleValue];
    
    //MKUserLocation *userLocation = mapView.userLocation; 
    
    double miles = 10.0;
    double scalingFactor = ABS( (cos(2 * M_PI * curLat / 360.0) )); ...

Comment: I just noticed in an earlier comment you said you now have "nothing in viewWillAppear".  As mentioned in the answer, just put `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;` in `viewWillAppear` and the rest of the code that was in `viewWillAppear` should now be in `didUpdateUserLocation`.  I duplicated your setup and problem and the changes in the answer worked for me.  I'll post an example of what the code should look like.

Comment: I just put the showUserLocation back in viewWillAppear. It's still a blue screen and it's still not calling the didUpdateUserLocation. Please post your code. Really appreciated all your help so far!

Comment: The answer was updated with the code that works for me.  I'm not sure what else the problem could be.  If you can post your project somewhere and give a link, I'll take a look at it.